# sequence of analytic functions on an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ that converges uniformly on compact subsets

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, functions

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of analytic functions on $U$. Suppose that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on any compact subsets of $U$ to a function $f$. Let $w\in U$ be an isolated zero of $f$. Prove that there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ and a sequence $(z_n)$ in $U$ converging to $w$ such that $f_n(z_n)=0$ for all $n\geq n_0$.

I have no idea how to prove this. How to use the analytic condition?

Comment: I think the key might be to use Gauss' Mean Value Theorem or Cauchy's Integral Formula with the function $f$ at $w$.

Comment: I still do not know how to solve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as Hurwitz's theorem. Here's a *sketch* of one of possible proofs. Suppose the statement is false. Then there is $r>0$ such that for infinitely many indices $n_k$, the function $f_{n_k}$ does not have a zero in the disk $D=\{z:|z-w |<r\}$. Make $r$ smaller, if needed, so that $f\ne 0$ on the circle $\partial D = \{z:|z-w |=r\}$. Then the minimum of $|f|$ on $\partial  D$ is  positive; let $m$ be this minimum. For large enough $k$, $$\min_{\partial D} |f_{n_k}| \ge m/2$$ Since $f_{n_k}$ does not vanish in $D$, the minimum modulus principle applies: $|f_{n_k}|\ge m/2$ everywhere in $D$. But this contradicts the fact that $$\lim_{k\to \infty} f_{n_k}(w) = f(w)=0$$